# What are some general tips/pieces of advice for speeding up navigation in the 3D Viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, performance, navigation

I was handed a massive file recently where the 3D viewport struggles to keep up with my mouse commands (panning, zooming, selecting, etc.), even though my machine should have excellent performance on-paper, which has me wondering about what I hope is a simple, acceptable, and fairly-generalized question: how can I speed things up a bit?

I'm not finding a post on here that gathers this information, and I feel that it would be helpful to have. There are surely at least a few ways to improve performance in this regard, so what are some of the typical methods, and what are some less well-known options?

Comment: Sorry but that question is off-topic for this site and likely to be closed. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.